# Estimating the multivariate normal distribution parameters from a set of 3D points

Tags: curve-fitting, matplotlib

I have a set of 3D points, which look as follows:
[image]

They form a shape similar to Gaussian/parabolic function or a mixture of these and **my goal is to extract this shape**.

I thought I could estimate parameters of a multivariate Gaussian from these points and in such way get a similar shape, however, they do not follow the normal distribution. So this is what I do to get a multivariate normal distribution from these data points.

I create a distribution of the points, where the probability for a point at (x,y) to occur is equal to z. Also, I normalize the z component, so that sum of all z components = 1. This gives me distribution which could be fed to Gaussian Mixture Model to estimate the parameters.

So I already implemented this and everything works nicely, but now I need to write it down with more theory behind and cannot figure it out.

**Is it some well-known method?**

**How could this be modelled formally?**

I was suggested to have a look at Gaussian Mixture Regression, but couldn't connect the dots.

**EDIT:** The x and y plane represents coordinates on a surface and z the amplitude of the sound generated at (x,y) position. The points were collected by scanning the surface with a sensor which emits sound with increasing intensity as we move towards the centre of the plot and decreases once moved away from the centre. Sample audio field could be found [here](http://ufile.io/jdvbu).

Comment: It would help to explain how these points were obtained and to clarify what they mean.  As illustrated and explained, you have a nonlinear regression problem ("curve fitting,") not a problem of estimating a distribution or mixture model.

Comment: @whuber Thanks for your observation, I added more info in the edit

Comment: Thank you: that clarifies that you are fitting a *response surface* to the data.  Although it could have a Gaussian shape (the graphic suggests that would be a poor fit), this is decidedly not a distribution-fitting problem.  The apparent mathematical similarities may be leading you astray.

Comment: @whuber Hmm, I understand that the points do not represent the distribution but I thought I could convert them to a distribution in order to do GMM and in such way fit multivariate normal. What would be your suggestion to fit such data points?

Comment: If you post a link to the data, I will run it through my online curve and surface fitting web site's "function finder" and see what equation it comes up with.

Comment: @JamesPhillips That would be great! [Here's](https://uploadfiles.io/qj95l) the link to a numpy array of the 3D points or do you prefer raw text? Thanks

Comment: @JamesPhillips On the other hand, the plot might not necessarily look like that and could be elliptical (as it would be formed by two separated gaussian curves), hence finding a single fitting function might not be very useful

Comment: Here is a 7.8 Mbyte 3D rotating scatterplot GIF animation of the raw data http://zunzun.com/temp/static_images/rotation.gif it appears that this dataset is unsuitable for surface fitting as the data points do not appear to lie on a surface. This may be obscured in your image by the point size, a smaller point size in the image should reveal this.

Comment: @James One wouldn't expect the points to lie exactly on a surface, because they represent sensor readings.  At a minimum we would expect them to include Poisson-like "shot noise."  This calls for something like a generalized linear model with a 2D spline, or even a nonlinear version of the GLM.

Comment: When I calibrated X-ray aluminum thickness sensors in the USA, Japan and France the sensor readings lay on a surface, at the time we were using 3D surface polynomials for the industrial gauge calibrations. That is why I thought the sensor readings might lie on a surface, and showed visually why they did not do so.

Comment: @JamesPhillips Thank you for your help, however, this still doesn't answer my question if my method to treat z component as mixing coefficient in GMM context makes sense.

Comment: @whuber I am still puzzled and not convinced why I couldn't fit this surface with GMM treating z component as a mixing coefficient?